# Proxifying multiple applications with different proxies

Tags: 14.04

Is it possible to proxify multiple applications with different proxies?

A solution where a proxy could be specified in the terminal as an argument would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

Edit your:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh
```

Enter the details in this format.

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/ 
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
export telnet_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
```

This is for when using `wget`, `ftp`, `lftp`, `telnet` in terminal

`ssh` has no native `SOCKS` client support, you need to use a `ProxyCommand` for that, for instance with `socat`:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='socat - SOCKS4A:myproxy:%h:%p,socksuser=nobody' user@host
```

Or use things like `tsocks` to transparently use `SOCKS` for `TCP` traffic.

For `SOCKS5` with socat 2:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='socat - "SOCKS5:%h:%p|tcp:myproxy:1080"' user@host
```

For HTTP Proxy CONNECT method with socat 2:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='socat - "PROXY:%h:%p|tcp:myproxy:80"' user@host
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, seems to work well with what you've said. Is there a more "catch all" solution for non-traditional applications? Something doesn't have proxy configuration embedded by design.

Comment: You can make some kind of proxy tunel or vpn tunntl and route traffic through them